# connect to url in python

Tags: python, http, authentication, python-3.x

i am trying to connect to a url with a username and password with the following code:

```
urllib.request.urlopen("http://username:password@......etc...", None)
```

but i'm getting

```
urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
```

anyone know what's up?

Comment: What do you mean by URL with username and password? Do you mean a page that will return "401 Unauthorized".

Comment: yes, authentication is required to connect to this server

Comment: BTW, You need to use "@Gene" if you want me be notified because of your reply. (I saw this reply because I anticipated you don't know you need this)

Comment: @rach: What SilentGhost means is this: Go back to one of your old questions.  Decide which answer helped you most.  Click on the outline of a checkmark next to that answer.  Repeat for all of your questions.

Comment: @rach: That's a strange error. I get "Nonnumeric port". In any case it's clear that urllib doesn't accept the username:password@hostname syntax. So, What Gene said.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry. I didn't notice you are using py3k.
See [urllib.request - FancyURLopener](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.FancyURLopener). I personally don't know py3k very well.
Basically, you need to subclass `urllib.request.FancyURLopener`, override `prompt_user_passwd(host, realm)`, and then call `YourClass.urlopen(url)`.

Below is for py2

This is what you want, [urllib2 - Basic Authentication](http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html#id6)
Below is the code from that page, just in case some day the link rot.

```
# create a password manager
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

# Add the username and password.
# If we knew the realm, we could use it instead of None.
top_level_url = "http://example.com/foo/"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)

handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)

# create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)

# use the opener to fetch a URL
opener.open(a_url)

# Install the opener.
# Now all calls to urllib2.urlopen use our opener.
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

Comment: @SlientGhost Thank you. I didn't notice that. I've update it soon.

Comment: @rach You're welcome. But I guess you'll have to figure out how it works on py3k. It's not as straightforward as py2 is. BTW, in this case, you can omit @Gene because I'm the owner of this answer and will automatically be notified.

Comment: It is exactly as straightforward, but instead of urllib2 you use urllib.request.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) for HTTP authentication.

HTTP doesn't handle authentication in the `user:password@host` way.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install 3rd party libraries then [`httplib2`](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) is both easier to use and more powerful alternative to [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html):

```
import httplib2

h = httplib2.Http("/path/to/cache-directory")
h.add_credentials(username, password)
response, content = h.request(url)
assert response.status == 200
```